# Запуск activity из RecyclerViewHolders

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Есть код:

```
    package com.example.hondle.biling;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.hondle.biling.activity.MainActivity;
import com.example.hondle.biling.activity.MainOnline;
import com.example.hondle.biling.activity.MainTabs;
import com.example.hondle.biling.fragments.MainOnlineFragment;


public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    public TextView countryName;
    public TextView countryName2;
    public  MainOnline main;
   // public ImageView countryPhoto;

    public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        countryName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
        countryName2 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name2);
        //countryPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_photo);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (getPosition() == 1){
            Intent Tokens = new Intent(MainOnline.this, MainTabs.class);
            startActivity(Tokens);
        }
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked Country Position = " + getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Это класс RecyclerView взаимодействующий с CardView, хочу спомощью позиций запускать activity, но как то не получается у меня...

UPD: Спасибо за ответы, но не сочтите за наглость, но есть еще варианты?
идеи?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам необходим context для запуска Activity, самый простой способ передать его при создании вашего адаптера, после получить, записать и использовать при необходимости, вкратце это так:

MainActivity.class

```
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), myList);
```

...

CustomAdapter.class

```
private Context mContext;
```

...

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView){ 
mContext = context; 
myList = recyclerView;
}
```

...

```
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

---

Существуют и другие реализации, это одна из самых простых, на данном этапе этого будет достаточно, а дальше поймете разницу.

Comment: Мне следует создать обьект mAdapter, вместо MyAdapter указать свой адаптер, верно? а вместо myList что?

Answer (score 1):

Не передавайте ссылку на контекст в адаптер. Это приведет к утечке памяти.

Рекомендую использовать EventBus. К примеру, http://square.github.io/otto/

Передайте в конструктор Вашего RecyclerView адаптера ссылку на bus, и в адаптере вызывайте post с соответствующим event.

Обработку событий event сделайте в Вашей основной активити, где и запускайте дочерние активити в обычном режиме.

Comment: Если вам не трудно, не могли бы написать примеру, именно к моему случаю. Просто я новичек, а времени разбираться в этом по долгу нету. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А почему приведет к утечке памяти ?